# Uninstall Windows 8.1 to run Ubuntu 14.04 as the single OS on my laptop?

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall

From the beginning I had Windows 8.1 installed on my laptop. Then I installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows by shrinking a drive on Windows and installing Ubuntu by usb to the latter one. Now I want to uninstall windows 8.1 to run Ubuntu 14.04 as the single OS on my laptop. If I uninstall windows 8.1, do I still have Ubuntu 14.04 on my boot options? Or I need to do something else?

Comment: Do you want a clean install on the entier hard drive or just windows gone

Comment: Just to remove windows and make its partition empty.

Answer (score 2):

I would advice to keep the W8 recovery partition that probably is on your system intact. You never know if you want to turn back.

You have several options. The most common 3:

1. re-install Ubuntu 14.04 and during partitioning remove all the partitions you want to use and re-partition them as wanted (whatever rocks your boat: / or / swap or / swap /home or / swap /home /etc /boot). You can do that automatically or manually. In the  end all is used for Ubuntu. Problem: this will remove your current Ubuntu and its files.

   If that is not wanted...
2. [Burn and boot a gParted live dvd](http://gparted.org/livecd.php). Remove all unwanted partitions and after that is done choose to resize the partition that is adjecent to the unallocated space. That will probably be the root partition. After this is done the space from the Windows partition will become available to Ubuntu (Option 4: you can only do resizing to adjecent partitions; if you want it added to another partition you need to shrink and enlarge partitions several times; this will take a lot of time depending on how full your system is).
3. [Burn and boot a gParted live dvd](http://gparted.org/livecd.php). Remove all unwanted partitions and after this is done format the unallocated space as EXT4 and give it a mountpoint. That way you end up with an extra partition and can freely use that space after you changed the owner and group to your user (`chown $USER:$USER /media/{mountpont}/`.

The reason I advice a live gparted is that this makes sure all partitions are unmounted and you can change the partitions at will.

Answer (score 0):

Boot ubuntu and open a terminal, run

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Open this in the dash (top left) and right click your windows partitio

Choose delete click the green tick to apply, this will make just blank space, you can format this to what ever you like.

Then do this in a terminal and reboot

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: he should however remember to do a "sudo update-grub" before restarting. Or else the windows option will still be available in the boot manager.